# Play video on hover disappears but re-appears when I inspect the page

Tags: html, video

I am trying to play a video when the user browses over the video with their mouse. I am using the code below to do so:

```
<video poster="img/video1.jpg" src="video/movie.mp4" id="id0" onMouseOver="id0.play()" onMouseOut="id0.pause()" onclick="window.location='video/movie.mp4';id0.pause()" loop ></video>
```

So it will show the banner/poster, but when I mouse over it, it vanishes. Then when I go to inspect the the code with chrome, it shows up right after I inspect and it works if I browse over it. Anyone have any tips, tricks, or brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that having the onMouseOver trigger the play isn't correctly causing the element to re-draw (the video is actually playing, I can hear my sample!)

you can work around it my modifying the onMouseOver to force the controls to appear and then disappear (usually too quick to see):

`...onMouseOver="id0.play();id0.controls=true;id0.controls=false"...`

tested and seems to work okay in both Safari and Chrome on OSX